# Open modal dialog from webpart in the parent page

Tags: web-part, javascript, sharepoint-addin, modal-dialog, jsom

I have written a SharePoint application which is embedded in a page as an AppPart. 
Now I want to open a modal dialog in the parent page. This code opens the dialog only in the current AppPart:

```
function openModalDialog() {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

    options.title = "Application";
    options.width = 400;
    options.height = 600;
    options.url = "MyApplicationSite.aspx";

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

But I want to open it in the parent page. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, however it'll require adding code to the parent page and utilizing `window.postMessage()`.  You will have to add an event listener on the parent page to listen for the message, and then open the dialog:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

var receiveMessage = function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== "your app") return; //event.origin will identify the sender of the message

    console.info(event.data); // event.data will contain data sent by the postMessage

    event.source.postMessage( returnObject, event.origin ); // event.source allows you to send a reply message with whatever data (the returnObject) you want/need to.
}
```

Your app part will have to post a message:

```
var messageData = { 
    url: "url to open in dialog",
    whateverElseYouMayNeedToSend: ""
};

window.parent.postMessage(messageData, document.referrer);
```

And if need be, add an event listener to the app part if you need to send data back to the app part.

For info on `postMessage()`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).  For an example of how it's used in SharePoint, see [this](http://blog.ctp.com/2014/02/05/resizing-app-parts-with-postmessage-in-sharepoint-2013/) and [this](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/use-postmessage-shim-give-sharepoint-client-app-parts-information/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used below mention Script on Client webpart

---

```
   function SpotlightVideoPopup(youtubeurl) {
        var decodeurl = decodeURIComponent(youtubeurl);
        var url = decodeurl;
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.title = "Spotlight Video";
        options.width = 800;
        options.height = 600;
        options.url = url;
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = CloseDialogCallback;
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);           
    }

    function CloseDialogCallback() {
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose', 1);
    }
```

---

Please help me , where we need to add window.parent.postMessage(messageData, document.referrer); code . thanks