# SharePoint Online - How to make custom forms launch in a dialog?

Tags: custom-form, modal-dialog, list-form, dialog-framework

I've created a new custom edit form for a document library in SharePoint designer.  "Launch forms in a dialog?" option in advanced settings is set to "yes", however, it does not affect anything.  The form always shows as page.  Out-of-box Edit form for a customized document type always pops up as a dialog, however, all other forms, including out-of-box forms for customized link to a document and document set, always appear as page.
Please help.  Is there a way to specify page appearance on the page definition?

Answer (score 0):

1. For simpler way use `window.Open`

   ```
   var x = screen.width / 2 - 750 / 2;
   var y = screen.height / 2 - 600 / 2;
   <a class="evidences" title="To add evidences" onclick="window.open(\'' + url + '\', \'\', \'width=750,height=600,left=' + x + ',top=' + y + '\')"><div></div></a>
   ```
2. Use SP Modal Dialog window

   [Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70274/sharepoint-2013-app-part-and-modal-dialogs)

Comment: Sabitha, thank you for your answer.  I haven't specified that I wanted to open a dialog box using custom action defined through SharePoint Designer.  I've ended up calling javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle.